# Aws Alexa Rank History

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to get alexa rank history for a website using php. I get the following results and its daily basis.

Date: 2014-12-22 Rank: 1

Date: 2014-12-23 Rank: 1

Is there any way to get the result based on month like

Date: 2014-12-22 Rank: 1

Date: 2015-1-22 Rank: 1

The code that is used by me is:

```
http://awis.amazonaws.com/?
            Action=TrafficHistory
            &AWSAccessKeyId=[Your AWS Access Key ID]
            &Signature=[signature calculated from request]
            &SignatureMethod=[HmacSha1 or HmacSha256]
            &SignatureVersion=2
            &Timestamp=[timestamp used in signature]
            &Url=[Valid URL]
            &ResponseGroup=History
            &Range=[maximum number of results]
            &Start=[start date for results]
```

Start Date is 20141222 and Range is 2

Do i need to pass any end date or 'params' to get the data monthly? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a huge database of historical alexa rankings: http://alexarankdb.com/